# Notifiy Activity when AsyncTask is ready?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have this activity that class a Login class inside an onclick event. My Login class basically does a http post and parses the XML response from the server. This happens inside a thread in the constructor of the Login class.

My problem is in this part:

```
Login login = new TvsLogin(emailEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString());
if(login.isErrorOccurd()){

}
else{

}
```

Basically, while the constructor of login is doing it's magic, the rest of my code gets executed and `login.isErrorOccurd()` appears false and my else block gets executed, even when there's an error.

Any suggestions how I should fix this? Login can take time so it makes sense to do it in a thread, but it's not working out the way I expected.

**EDIT:**

Like Pixie says, I'll have to use an AsyncTask. I would still like to do the reporting inside my Activity though. How do I do this? (Is this a good idea, or should I just do this inside the `onPostExecute()` method in my Activity?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing strange in this behavior. Login is not checked in secondary thread when `login.isErrorOccurd()` method is called. You can use `Activity.runOnUiThread()` method to notify your activity about login check results or you can use `AsyncTask` class to let it do this stuff for you. But anyway error checking will be in other part of code.

Comment: You can, but you can't do it right after starting a thread that checks login. This thread must notify your activity about result of checking and then activity should perform some action depending on checking results.

Comment: How Exactly do I notify the activity from my AsyncTask class?

Comment: You should return `Boolean` result from `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` method. And in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` you can check this result. It will be passed there from `doInBackground()`. `onPostExecute()` executes on the UI thread so that's like an implicit notification. If your `AsyncTask` is an inner class of an `Activity`, you can call activity's method like `YourActivity.this.processLoginResult()`.

Comment: Hi Pixie whats the best approach if the async task is NOT running directly from the UI's Activity? i have a case where I am passing the UI activity object through to my class containing the `Async` class, however when calling back to the ui to "processLoginResult()" ie, `ParentUIActivity.processLoginResult()` will this be a memory concern because I'm worried it would result in the `Async` class unable to be garbage collected until the parent is finished

Comment: It's not obvious to answer this question in general. For instance, you can perform authentication in a service. In your case you can cancel the task with interrupt or have a weak reference on the activity.